# Twillio Studio gather/split using first input

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

New to Twilio Studio.

I have a "chain of events" that all play a "message" and gather DTMF/ touch TONES. [Gather input/split based on]

If I press "4" on the first gather/split, on the second gather/split it will always choose "4" even if I press "1" and ignore my actual input.

Do I have to re-initialize the input buffer somehow?  How can I get the second gather/split to respond to the actual input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the variable you are evaluating on the next split based on widget refers to the most recent gather widgets input.

You can also view the Studio execution logs to view the underlying evaluation logic.

[Split Based On... Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on)